# Jquery Validate Form issue while split by 2 screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the JQuery validate for my contact form. It was a single page form. But right now its split by 2 set. First set has few fields with a continue button. Then second set will be given by continue button. The continue btn validating without an issue. But it doesn't give the alert like the final submit btn.

Can you help me to resolve this

My Markup

```
<form name="contact" id="contact" method="post" action="http://action.com">
  <div id="form-fields">
    <!-- Form Step One -->
    <div id="form_step1">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="request_label">Program of Interest</label>
        <select id="CurriculumID" name="CurriculumID">
          <option selected="selected" value="">What program would you like to study</option>
        </select>
        <br />
      </div>


      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="request_label">First Name</label>
        <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" title="First Name" />
        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="request_label">Last Name</label>
        <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" title="Last Name" />
        <br />
      </div>
      <!-- CLOSING (FIRST NAME AND LAST NAME) -->
      <div class="req_btn_wrapper">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next">
          <img src="images/next_btn.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form Step Two -->
    <div id="form_step2">
      <a href="#" id="back-button"></a>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="request_label">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" title="Email" />
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="split-form-row">
          <label class="request_label">Phone</label>
          <input name="dayphone" id="dayphone" class="form_phone" type="text" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" title="Phone" />
          <br />
        </div>
        <div class="split-form-row">
          <label class="request_label">Zip Code</label>
          <input name="zip" id="zip" class="form_zip" type="text" title="Zip Code" />
          <br />
        </div>


        <div id="cityStateInput">
          <input name="city" id="city" type="text" title="City" placeholder="City" />
          <br />
          <select name="state" id="state">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Select a State:</option>
            <option value="N/A">Orange</option>
            <option value="N/A">lorem</option>
          </select>
          <br />
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="request_label">Year</label>
        <select name="gradyear" id="gradyear">
          <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- Radio -->

      <div class="radio_row">
        <p id="military" class="military_label">Are you working in the military?</p>
        <div class="radio_option">
          <input type="radio" name="verify" value="Yes"><span id="yes1" for="yes">Yes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="radio_option">
          <input type="radio" name="verify" value="No" checked="checked"><span id="no1">No</span> 
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Radio -->

      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!-- CLOSING CLEAR -->
      <div class="req_btn_wrapper">
        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="images/btn_submit_request.png" value="" />
      </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

My Js script

```
// Validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#contact").validate({
  ignore: ":hidden",
  onclick: false,
  onfocusout: false,
  onsubmit: true,
  onkeyup: false,
  onkeydown: false,
  rules: {
    // Insert fields from the form
    email: {
      email: true
    },
    zip: {
      minlength: 5,
      required: true,
      checkLabel: true,
      zipUS: true
    },
    city: {
      checkLabel: true,
      required: true
    },
    dayphone: {
      required: true,
      checkPhoneValue: true
    },
    state: {
      required: true
    },
    firstname: {
      required: true,
      checkLabel: true
    },
    lastname: {
      required: true,
      checkLabel: true
    },
  },
  messages: {
    // Place custom error messages
    CurriculumID: "Please select a program.",
    firstname: "Please enter your first name.",
    lastname: "Please enter your last name.",
    dayphone: "Please enter a valid phone number.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    zip: "Please enter a valid Zip code.",
    gradyear: "Please select H.S. graduation year.",
    city: "Please enter your city.",
    state: "Please select your state."
  },
  // Error placement
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    try {
      if (submitted) {
        var summary = "Please fix the following: \n\n";
        $.each(errorList, function() {
          summary += " - " + this.message + "\n";
        });
        alert(summary);
        submitted = false;
      }
      //this.defaultShowErrors();
    } catch (err) {
      Raven.captureException(err);
    }
  },
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    try {
      submitted = true;
    } catch (err) {
      Raven.captureException(err);
    }
  }
}); // END FORM VALIDATION


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_step2').hide();
  var validateStep1 = function() {
    var isValid_1 = $('#CurriculumID').valid();
    var isValid_2 = $('#firstname').valid();
    var isValid_3 = $('#lastname').valid();

    if (isValid_1 && isValid_2 && isValid_3) {
      $('#form_step1').hide();
      $('#form_step2').show();
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Show step 2
  $('#next').click(function() {
    validateStep1();
  });
  $('#back-button').click(function() {
    $('#form_step1').show();
    $('#form_step2').hide();
  });

  // Check input value against inline label
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkLabel", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != element.title;
  }, "Please enter a value.");


})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues that *could* break the expected behavior of the jQuery Validate plugin...

```
$("#contact").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    onclick: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    onsubmit: true,    // <- NEVER set to 'true'
    onkeyup: false,
    onkeydown: false,  // <- No such thing
    ....
```

- There is absolutely no such thing called `onkeydown`.  Please refer to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for all available options.
- The `onsubmit` option must never be set to `true` as this breaks the built-in `onsubmit` function.  This option can only be set to `false` or an over-riding function.  If you want to keep the default submit functionality un-altered, then you must remove the `onsubmit` option from your `.validate()` method.

**See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit)**

> *"Set to false to use only other events for validation.*
>
> *Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation.*
>
> ***A boolean true is not a valid value***".

---

> The continue btn validating without an issue. But it doesn't give the alert like the final submit btn.

As far as your issue, you need to look at your JavaScript error console.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: submitted
```

I removed the `if (submitted)` conditional within `showErrors` and got your "next" button working...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vpgmnLg0/**